# Window function to count occurrences in last 10 minutes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I can use a traditional subquery approach to count the occurrences in the last ten minutes. For example, this:

```
drop table if exists [dbo].[readings]
go

create table [dbo].[readings](
    [server] [int] NOT NULL,
    [sampled] [datetime] NOT NULL
)
go

insert into readings
values
(1,'20170101 08:00'),
(1,'20170101 08:02'),
(1,'20170101 08:05'),
(1,'20170101 08:30'),
(1,'20170101 08:31'),
(1,'20170101 08:37'),
(1,'20170101 08:40'),
(1,'20170101 08:41'),
(1,'20170101 09:07'),
(1,'20170101 09:08'),
(1,'20170101 09:09'),
(1,'20170101 09:11')
go

-- Count in the last 10 minutes - example periods 08:31 to 08:40, 09:12 to 09:21
select server,sampled,(select count(*) from readings r2 where r2.server=r1.server and r2.sampled <= r1.sampled and r2.sampled > dateadd(minute,-10,r1.sampled)) as countinlast10minutes
from readings r1
order by server,sampled
go
```

How can I use a window function to obtain the same result ? I've tried this:

```
select server,sampled,
count(case when sampled <= r1.sampled and sampled > dateadd(minute,-10,r1.sampled) then 1 else null end) over (partition by server order by sampled rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as countinlast10minutes
-- count(case when currentrow.sampled <= r1.sampled and currentrow.sampled > dateadd(minute,-10,r1.sampled) then 1 else null end) over (partition by server order by sampled rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as countinlast10minutes
from readings r1
order by server,sampled
```

But the result is just the running count. Any system variable that refers to the current row pointer ? currentrow.sampled ?

Comment: try this 
select count(1) from readings r1 
where datediff(minute, getdate(), sampled) <= 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a very pleasing answer but one possibility is to first create a helper table with all the minutes

```
CREATE TABLE #DateTimes(datetime datetime primary key);

WITH E1(N) AS 
(
    SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
                            (1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) V(N)
)                                       -- 1*10^1 or 10 rows
, E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b)   -- 1*10^2 or 100 rows
, E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b)   -- 1*10^4 or 10,000 rows
, E8(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E4 b)   -- 1*10^8 or 100,000,000 rows
 ,R(StartRange, EndRange)
 AS (SELECT MIN(sampled),
            MAX(sampled)
     FROM   readings)
 ,N(N)
 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
              OVER (
                ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS N
     FROM   E8)
INSERT INTO #DateTimes
SELECT TOP (SELECT 1 + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, StartRange, EndRange) FROM R) DATEADD(MINUTE, N.N - 1, StartRange)
FROM   N,
       R;
```

And then with that in place you could use `ROWS BETWEEN 9 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`

```
WITH T1 AS
( SELECT  Server,
                  MIN(sampled) AS StartRange,
                  MAX(sampled) AS EndRange
         FROM     readings
         GROUP BY Server )
SELECT      Server,
            sampled,
            Cnt
FROM        T1
CROSS APPLY
            ( SELECT   r.sampled,
                                COUNT(r.sampled) OVER (ORDER BY N.datetime ROWS BETWEEN 9 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Cnt
                      FROM      #DateTimes N
                      LEFT JOIN readings r
                      ON        r.sampled = N.datetime
                                AND r.server = T1.server
                      WHERE     N.datetime BETWEEN StartRange AND EndRange ) CA
WHERE       CA.sampled IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY    sampled
```

The above assumes that there is at most one sample per minute and that all the times are exact minutes. If this isn't true it would need another table expression pre-aggregating by datetimes rounded to the minute.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is not a simple exact replacement for your subquery using window functions.

Window functions operate on a set of rows and allow you to work with them based on partitions and order. 
What you are trying to do isn't the type of partitioning that we can work with in window functions. 
To generate the partitions we would need to be able to use window functions in this instance would just result in overly complicated code.

I would suggest `cross apply()` as an alternative to your subquery.

I am not sure if you meant to restrict your results to within 9 minutes, but with `sampled > dateadd(...)` that is what is happening in your original subquery.

Here is what a window function could look like based on partitioning your samples into 10 minute windows, along with a `cross apply()` version.

```
select 
    r.server
  , r.sampled
  , CrossApply       = x.CountRecent
  , OriginalSubquery = (
      select count(*) 
      from readings s
      where s.server=r.server
        and s.sampled <= r.sampled
        /* doesn't include 10 minutes ago */
        and s.sampled > dateadd(minute,-10,r.sampled)
        )
  , Slices           = count(*) over(
      /* partition by server, 10 minute slices, not the same thing*/
      partition by server, dateadd(minute,datediff(minute,0,sampled)/10*10,0)
      order by sampled
      )
from readings r
  cross apply (
    select CountRecent=count(*) 
    from readings i
    where i.server=r.server
      /* changed to >= */
      and i.sampled >= dateadd(minute,-10,r.sampled) 
      and i.sampled <= r.sampled 
     ) as x
order by server,sampled
```

results: http://rextester.com/BMMF46402

```
+--------+---------------------+------------+------------------+--------+
| server |       sampled       | CrossApply | OriginalSubquery | Slices |
+--------+---------------------+------------+------------------+--------+
|      1 | 01.01.2017 08:00:00 |          1 |                1 |      1 |
|      1 | 01.01.2017 08:02:00 |          2 |                2 |      2 |
|      1 | 01.01.2017 08:05:00 |          3 |                3 |      3 |
|      1 | 01.01.2017 08:30:00 |          1 |                1 |      1 |
|      1 | 01.01.2017 08:31:00 |          2 |                2 |      2 |
|      1 | 01.01.2017 08:37:00 |          3 |                3 |      3 |
|      1 | 01.01.2017 08:40:00 |          4 |                3 |      1 |
|      1 | 01.01.2017 08:41:00 |          4 |                3 |      2 |
|      1 | 01.01.2017 09:07:00 |          1 |                1 |      1 |
|      1 | 01.01.2017 09:08:00 |          2 |                2 |      2 |
|      1 | 01.01.2017 09:09:00 |          3 |                3 |      3 |
|      1 | 01.01.2017 09:11:00 |          4 |                4 |      1 |
+--------+---------------------+------------+------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Martin and SqlZim, for your answers. I'm going to raise a Connect enhancement request for something like %%currentrow that can be used in window aggregates. I'm thinking this would lead to much more simple and natural sql:

select count(case when sampled <= %%currentrow.sampled and sampled > dateadd(minute,-10,%%currentrow.sampled) then 1 else null end) over (...whatever the window is...)

We can already use expressions like this:

select count(case when sampled <= getdate() and sampled > dateadd(minute,-10,getdate()) then 1 else null end) over (...whatever the window is...)

so thinking would be great if we could reference a column that's in the current row.

Comment: The standard SQL way of doing what you want here is to use `RANGE` instead of `ROWS` but SQL Server does not support this fully enough. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/sqlref/sql-reference-window-clause.html